# Set Shell Variable from ConsoleApplication in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd

I have a batchfile that run a vb.net Console App.

I need to change some var's e.g. "vbrun" from the current commandline to use it in other batch files, they run after the Console App

as example test.bat

```
@echo off
set vbrun=true
myVBTool.exe
echo %vbrun%
```

Comment: So what have you tried?  Show your research effort, or else your question will be down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, the environment variables are stored inside a memory area called the environment block. This memory is not shared, each process has its own copy. When a parent process starts a child process, the parent customize the environemtn block of the child or give to it a copy of its own environment block.

But you need the inverse. You want to change the environment of the parent process (`cmd.exe`) from a child process (`myVBTool.exe`).

In short, no, this can not be done.

But, of course, a process can change its own environment. In your case, you need a way for your tool to indicate to its parent process that the variable needs to be changed.

You can set a return value for your application that will be stored as `errorlevel` and depending on it set your variable

```dos
rem ....
myVBtool.exe
if errorlevel 1 set "vbrun=false"
rem ....
```

Or your application can write to stdout and the batch file can process this output

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('myVBTool.exe') do set "vbrun=%%a"
```